# keyerror in Django REST Framework UserSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add some functionality to the create API handler for a new user. I have an associated UserProfile table that I want to add the newly created user to, adding in the value of a URL parameter.

The POST api call looks like this:

```
.../api/users/?username=fred&email=me@me.com&password=1234&data=whatever
```

The serializer for the standard Django user table is:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'email')
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        the_user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email']
        )

        the_user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        the_user.save()

        # Create associated user profile
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(
            data=validated_data['data'],
            user=the_user.id
        )
        user_profile.save()

        return the_user
```

The view for the User stuff is:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

My new UserProfile table model is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I haven't created a view or serializer for the UserProfile as all I want to do at the moment is add a row when a new user is created and put in the value of the data parameter passed in the POST url.

Django reports the following error when I create a new user:

```
KeyError: 'data'
```

Comment: You should post the _full Exception traceback_. Without reading the traceback it's _much_ harder to determine the cause of the bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# Create associated user profile
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(
    data=validated_data['data'],
    user=the_user.id
)
```

`validated_data` doesn't have a `data` key in `UserSerializer.create`. It only contains the keys you define in the serializer's Meta.fields

```
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'email')
```

Comment: Could please help me resolving this keyerror
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49587819/django-keyerror-while-fetching-multiple-tables?noredirect=1#comment86185987_49587819